# Operands could not be broadcast together with shapes : with certain batch sizes

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to make auto-encoder. 
My code was working before I update to `tensorflow2.0`, but it is not working with updated the version of `tensorflow`.

```
# Define batch_size / epochs 
epochs = 200
batch_size = 128

encoder = encoder_model(inputs)
decoder = decoder_model()
# instantiate VAE model
outputs = decoder(encoder(inputs))
ae = Model(inputs, outputs, name='ae_mlp')

reconstruction_loss = mse(inputs, outputs)
ae.add_loss(reconstruction_loss)
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001)
ae.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='mse')
history = ae.fit(x_trn, x_trn, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, validation_data=(x_val, x_val))
```

It keeps getting an error with most of batch sizes.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-38e600fb7073> in <module>
    135     opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001)
    136     ae.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='mse')
--> 137     history = ae.fit(x_trn, x_trn, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, validation_data=(x_val, x_val))
    138 
    139     """ save model"""

~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    726         max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
    727         workers=workers,
--> 728         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
    729 
    730   def evaluate(self,

~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py in fit(self, model, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, **kwargs)
    322                 mode=ModeKeys.TRAIN,
    323                 training_context=training_context,
--> 324                 total_epochs=epochs)
    325             cbks.make_logs(model, epoch_logs, training_result, ModeKeys.TRAIN)
    326 

~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py in run_one_epoch(model, iterator, execution_function, dataset_size, batch_size, strategy, steps_per_epoch, num_samples, mode, training_context, total_epochs)
    170             batch_outs,
    171             batch_start=step * batch_size,
--> 172             batch_end=step * batch_size + current_batch_size)
    173       cbks.make_logs(model, batch_logs, batch_outs, mode)
    174       step += 1

~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_utils.py in aggregate(self, batch_outs, batch_start, batch_end)
    132       self.results[0] += batch_outs[0]
    133     else:
--> 134       self.results[0] += batch_outs[0] * (batch_end - batch_start)
    135     # Metrics (always stateful, just grab current values.)
    136     self.results[1:] = batch_outs[1:]

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (128,) (116,) (128,)
```

I tried with `batch_size=1`, and `batch_size=2`, it gave me no errors, takes much more time though.

When I try to do it with bigger batch_size, it always give me the error. 
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please show your model definition. Are you sure you're not forcing it to have batch size=128? You should not force the batch size in the model unless you have a really strong reason for that, in which case you must make your data compatible with that specific batch size.

Comment: @DanielMöller I used input_shape = (74, ), and hidden layers for encoder and decoder were (256, ), (128, ), (64, ) and the latent shape = (4, ). And I have the input data shape = (11466, 74). How can I properly decide batch size? I have always just randomly selected batch size = 64, 128, or 256.. Is that not a good practice?

Comment: Please show your model definition. And did you notice that you are using two losses and both are `mse` on inputs and outputs?

Comment: @DanielMöller Oh I didn't know that. Thanks,What do you mean by model definition? Do you need entire code?

Comment: @DanielMöller This problem was because of the version of Keras (in Tensorflow). After I install Keras (individually from Tensorflow) and update the version, problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

This problem was due to the version of Keras (in Tensorflow). After I install Keras (individually aside from Tensorflow) and update the version, problem solved!